# Second background service does not start

Tags: android, android-service

I defined two background services for my app. But only one of the, the AttachService starts. In LogCat I can see the starting log messages of the attachService but nothing from the PenManagerService. I defined for each service a startup receiver

```
public class StartupCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, PenManagerService.class);
        context.startService(service);

    }

}

public class AttachmentStartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = AttachmentStartupReceiver.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");

        Intent attachSvc = new Intent(context, AttachService.class);
        context.startService(attachSvc);

    }

}
```

Here the definition of the two services in the manifest

```
   <service
        android:name="de.android.services.PenManagerService"
        android:process=":PenManagerService" >
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="de.android.services.AttachService"
        android:icon="@drawable/loading_icon"
        android:label="@string/attachServiceName"
        android:process=":attachServiceBackground" />


    <receiver
        android:name="de.android.services.StartupCompletedReceiver"
        android:process=":PenManagerService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="de.android.AttachmentStartupReceiver"
        android:process=":attachServiceBackground" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Both services extends the IntentService and in their onCreate I have a log message, but only the one from the attachService shows up in the log.

Comment: why can't you start both services in same BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: I tried it already to start the PenManagerService from the AttachmentStartupReceiver, which starts succesfully the attachmentService but it has no effect. The PenManagerService does not start